# If MVC2 uses aspx pages and master pages is it okay to use asp.net server controls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Ive noticed that MVC 2 uses masterpages and ascx pages. I'm used to using Razor pages but have to work on an older project. So I'm wondering if it is okay to use asp.net server controls on these aspx markup pages?

I know its advised not to plug into the page lifecycle but what about user controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use user controls, stick with Web Forms. User controls are not used with MVC. The MVC view engine does not have a page lifecycle like Web Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Your Usercontrols plug in to the WebForms page lifecycle, they maintain their state through ViewState. There are helpers that were created to render out controls to MVC but they are limited in the fact that they are read-only, the controls don't support posting back or any events like that.

http://malvinly.com/2011/02/28/using-web-forms-user-controls-in-an-asp-net-mvc-project/

You could create partials out of your own controls:

[Using webform user control on webform in MVC Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343961/using-webform-user-control-on-webform-in-mvc-project)